# Is there a way to get the object with max points

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static

If i create a class called Team and i have an attribute called point(int) and i create 10 Teams, all of them have some points. I want to define a function inside my class that return the team that has the max points. Do you have any suggestion? I can do it by defining an external function but i want to do it differently. Can i do it by defining an static function inside my class or use stream() inside a function in my class?

Thank you for the help and i'm sorry for my english and for the broad question

```
public class Team {
    int point;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correctly, then you could simply make a for-loop.

```
public static void GetTeamWithMaxPoints(ArrayList<Team> teams) {
   Team team = null;
   for(Team t : teams) {
     if(team == null || team.getPoint() < t.getPoint()) {
       team = t;
     }
   }
   return team;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a static map variable and each time the constructor is called, add a team object as the key and points as the value. That is, if a team has points when it is created. Then create a static function that checks the map for the max value and returns the team. 
(Correction you can just use an ArrayList, since each team already has a point field)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a static method in your class like this one:

```
public static Optional<Team> winner(Collection<Team> teams) {
    return teams.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(team -> team.point));
}
```

Adjust it if you prefer to return an Optional, a null or throw a Exception in case the Collection teams is empty.